# Getting Error: [$compile:multidir] using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am getting the following error while using datepicker of Angular.js.

Error message

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$compile/multidir?p0=datepicker&p1=&p2=da…-prev%3D%22%3Ci%20class%3D%26quot%3Bfa%20fa-arrow-circle-left%26quot%3B%3E
    at Error (native)
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:6:416
    at Q (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:69:353)
    at D (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:62:492)
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:68:182
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:118:334
    at n.$eval (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:132:452)
    at n.$digest (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:129:463)
    at n.$apply (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:133:236)
    at g (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:87:376)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Date :</span>
<datepicker date-format="dd-MM-y" button-prev='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>' button-next='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>'> 
<input type="text" name="birthdate" class="form-control" ng-model="date" placeholder="Add date" />
</datepicker>
</div>
```

I have already included the `720kb.datepicker` module and added the respective css and js files.Still i am getting the above type of error.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs is exporting a url to explain the error message which is

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=datepicker&p1=&p2=da%E2%80%A6-prev%3D%22%3Ci%20class%3D%26quot;fa%20fa-arrow-circle-left%26quot;%3E

in your case and explanation locates your prev button definition.

> Multiple directives [datepicker, da…-prev="{3}] asking for {4} on: {5}
>
> **Description** This error occurs when multiple directives are applied to
>   the same DOM element, and processing them would result in a collision
>   or an unsupported configuration.
>
> To resolve this issue remove one of the directives which is causing
>   the collision.
>
> Example scenarios of multiple incompatible directives applied to the
>   same element include:
>
> Multiple directives requesting isolated scope. Multiple directives
>   publishing a controller under the same name. Multiple directives
>   declared with the transclusion option. Multiple directives attempting
>   to define a template or templateURL.

Most probably `button-prev` or `button-next` is overlaping with `datepicker` directive.

Comment: That i have tested in that same file I have only one directive.

Comment: @ ibrahimbayer : Hi,Error actually arises when i including ui-bootstarp and 720kb.datepicker together.Can you help me to resolve this.